# Output of difflib.HTMLDiff.make_file() not rendered in browser

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, difflib

Using the two texts given by [PyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/difflib/index.html#html-output), `difflib.HtmlDiff.make_file()` is used to produce HTML output. Yet when saved and opened in a browser, the raw HTML is displayed rather than rendered as the expected table.

Is the output of `make_file()` malformed? See [here](http://pastebin.com/ebnB7xSC).

Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using python 3.5, and I am getting the html content **as given in your link** correctly rendered without any modification. You asked about `make_table` and `make_file`. This is from the link you have given:

> This example uses make_table(), which only returns the table tag containing the difference information. The make_file() method produces a fully-formed HTML file as output.

So the output you have shown is from `make_file()`, not `make_table()`.

---

*If you are using django* (just a wild guess) try this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ your_html_content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

You can also do the same using [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe):

```
{{ your_table_content|safe }}
```

From django docs:

> Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.
>   When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe)

Comment: Yes will-spotted - it's `make-file` I am using. This is not Django; I'm just playing around with difflib.