# Comparing two HTML files using Python difflib package

Tags: python, html, difflib

I am having issues with comparing two HTML files using Pythob difflib. While I was able to generate a comparison file that highlighted any changes, when I opened the comparison file, it displayed the raw HTML and CSS script/tags instead of the plain text.

E.g

```
<Html><Body><div class="a"> Text Here</div></Body></html>
```

instead of

```
Text Here
```

My Python Script is as follows:

```
import difflib

file1 = open('file1.html', 'r').readlines()
file2 = open('file2.html', 'r').readlines()
diffHTML = difflib.HtmlDiff()
htmldiffs = diffHTML.make_file(file1,file2)

with open('Comparison.html', 'w') as outFile:
     outFile.write(htmldiffs)
```

My input files looks something like this

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Text here</title>        
                    <style type="text/css">
            @media all {
                h1 {
                    margin: 0px;
                    color: #222222;
                }
                #page-title {
                    color: #222222;
                    font-size: 1.4em;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
                body {
                    font: 0.875em/1.231 tahoma, geneva, verdana, sans-serif;
                    padding: 30px;
                    min-width: 800px;
                }
                .divider {
                    margin: 0.5em 15% 0.5em 10%;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
                }
                
                }
                .section.header {
                    background-color: #303030;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
                    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
                }
                .section.subheader {
                    background-color: #CFCFCF;
                    color: #000;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    padding: 1px 5px;
                    margin: 0px auto 5px 0px;
                }
                
            
        
                .response_rule_prefix {
                    font-style: italic;
                }

                .exception-scope
                {
                    color: #666666;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                }

                .where-clause-header
                {
                    color:#AAAA99;
                }

                .section {
                    padding: 0em 0em 1.2em 0em;
                }

                #generated-Time {
                    padding-top:5px;
                    float:right;
                }
                #page-title, #generated-Time {
                    display: inline-block;
                }
            

        
            </style></head>

                    <body>
            <div id="title-section" class="section ">
                            <div id="page-branding">
                                <h1>Title</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div id="page-title">
                                Sub title
                            </div>
                            <div id="generated-Time">
                                Date & Time : Jul 2, 2020 2:42:48 PM
                            </div>
            </div>

                <div class="section header">General</div>
                <div id="general-section" class="section">
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-name-label">Text here</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-name-content" >Text here</span>
                </div>
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-description-label">Description A :</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-description-content""></span>Text here</span>
                </div>
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-label-label" class="general-detail-label">Description b:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-label-content" class="wrapping-text"></span>
                </div>
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-group-label" class="general-detail-label">Group:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-group-content" class="wrapping-text">Text here</span>
                </div>
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-status-label" class="general-detail-label">Status:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-status-content">
                            <label id="policy-status-message">Active</label>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-version-label" class="general-detail-label">Version:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-version-content" class="wrapping-text">7</span>
                </div>
                <div  class="general-detail-label-container">
                    <label id="policy-last-modified-label" class="general-detail-label">Last Modified:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="general-detail-content-container">
                        <span id="policy-last-modified-content" class="wrapping-text">Jun 15, 2020 2:41:48 PM</span>
                </div>
                </div>

                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Could you share your code as well as an example with inputs and expected output - a minimal reproducible example for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I have included a sample of my python script which I found from another thread and a sample of my two input files

Comment: I've just checked the HTML and it is incorrect. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and provide provide an input for file1 and file2 respectively. In order for you to get help you should prepare an example that is easily reproducible for anyone who will take on the task. What you have provided is incomplete.

Comment: I have changed the code slightly and deleted some irrelevant stuff. Essentially, the two files would should be very similar, only that file1 would be an earlier version of file2 and I am trying to determine what have changed between file1 (earlier version) and file2 (later version). My issue is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983301/output-of-difflib-htmldiff-make-file-not-rendered-in-browser . Despite trying different browsers, my issue is not solved. I can't seem to view the comparison file with the actual Html webpage but instead see the raw code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only looking for the text changes and not changes to the HTML, you could strip the output of HTML after the comparison. There are a number of ways to achieve this. The two that I first thought of was:

1. RegEx, because this is native in Python, and
2. BeautifulSoup, because it was created to read webpages

Create a function, using either of above methods, to strip the output of HTML

e.g. using BeautifulSoup

**UPDATE**

Reading through the documentation again, it seems to me that the comparison will yield the actual HTML too, however, you could create an additional output that only shows the text changes.

Also to avoid showing the whole document, I've set the `context` parameter to `True`

**Using BeautifulSoup**

```
import re
import difflib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def remove_html_bs(raw_html):
    data = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    data = data.findAll(text=True)
    
    def visible(element):
        if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
            return False
        elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element.encode('utf-8'))):
            return False
        return True
    
    result = list(filter(visible, data))

    return result

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    "Creates two comparison files"
    file1 = file1.readlines()
    file2 = file2.readlines()
    
    # Difference line by line - HTML
    difference_html = difflib.HtmlDiff(tabsize=8).make_file(file1, file2, context=True, numlines=5)
    # Difference line by line - raw
    difference_file = set(file1).difference(file2)
    
    # List of differences by line index
    difference_index = []
    for dt in difference_file:
        for index, t in enumerate(file1):
            if dt in t:
                difference_index.append(f'{index}, {remove_html_bs(dt)[0]}, {remove_html_bs(file2[index])[0]}')

    # Write entire line with changes
    with open('comparison.html', 'w') as outFile:
        outFile.write(difference_html)

    # Write only text changes, by index
    with open('comparison.txt', 'w') as outFile:
        outFile.write('LineNo, File1, File2\n')
        outFile.write('\n'.join(difference_index))

    return difference_html, difference_file


file1 = open('file1.html', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.html', 'r')

difference_html, difference_file = compare_files(file1, file2)
```

Comment: @okijuh123, let me know whether or not it worked for you :)

Comment: Don't seem to be removing the CSS tags and only printing the text. Based on what I have found on other threads, I should not be facing this issue at all and the comparison file should simply print and highlight the differences between two files.

Comment: could you include both file1 and file2, with only the parts in question that are problematic

Comment: Right now the entire file is being printed with the raw  html code and Css tags.

Comment: @okijuh123: I've updated the answer to help you out. However, as far as I can tell from the documentation; the HTML is supposed to show in the output file.

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is but I ran the code and it is still only producing the raw code when opened in browse.